# Can you get / store readings from a RadioShack 22-812 Digital Multimeter with a raspberry pi serial interaface?

Tags: serial

I was looking at an article on debricking an OpenWRT router using it's [serial interface by hooking it up to a Raspberry PI](https://johanbijker.blogspot.com/2012/07/tp-link-mr3420-serial-connection-with.html) when I realized that my old RadioShack 22-812 Digital Multimeter also has a serial interface; so is it possible to read / store readings from it using my Raspberry PI with Raspberian on it using the same serial interface?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly.

Remember that the Pi's UART is 3V3 TTL (low 0V, high 3.3V) whereas true serial RS232 is -25V for low and +25V for high which would destroy the Pi.

Check the electrical specs for the serial interface used by the multimeter.

Using a serial USB dongle at the Pi end may be safer as that should be 5V and bypasses the Pi GPIO.

Comment: But if RS232 is 25V to -25V then how can a 5V usb dongle survive?

Comment: Unless designed for RS232 it probably will not survive.  Hopefully it will be cheaper than buying a new Pi.